# Scala unused import statement with play framework in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to learn scala and play framework. I choosed IntelliJ Idea as ide. The problem is 
editor gives warning on imports like ; "unused import statements"

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
```

Also give warnings on declerations like ; "Cannot resolve symbol Controller"

```
object Login extends Controller
```

How can i remove warnings?

Steps i followed;

Create template idea project with play command;

Add scala compiler and library into external libraries.

IntelliJ Idea Version : 12.1 Community Editon

Comment: Did you activate the `Scala` plugin? And I'm sad to say that the Play! Framework is only supported in the Ultimate edition: [IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). But I'm not sure that that has anything to do with this problem.

Comment: yeap already activated the scala plugin. i guess ultimate edition is the solution unfortunately.

Comment: I usually run the Ultimate edition but installed the Community edition right now and I don't get the same error as you. The controllers are fine.

Comment: it's good to know that you didn't experience the problem with community edition, so then i was missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I did it (I'm using Play! 2.1.0):

```
C:\dev>play new community
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.7.0_15 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org

The new application will be created in C:\dev\community

What is the application name? [community]
>

Which template do you want to use for this new application?

1             - Create a simple Scala application
2             - Create a simple Java application

> 1
OK, application community is created.

Have fun!


C:\dev>cd community

C:\dev\community>play idea
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dev\community\project
[info] Set current project to community (in build file:/C:/dev/community/)
[info] Trying to create an Idea module community
[info] Updating {file:/C:/dev/community/}community...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Excluding folder target
[info] Created C:\dev\community/.idea/IdeaProject.iml
[info] Created C:\dev\community\.idea
[info] Excluding folder C:\dev\community\target\scala-2.10\cache
[info] Excluding folder C:\dev\community\target\resolution-cache
[info] Excluding folder C:\dev\community\target\streams
(commons-codec_commons-codec_1.6_test,List(commons-codec_commons-codec_1.3))
(org.apache.httpcomponents_httpcore_4.1.3_test,List(org.apache.httpcomponents_httpcore_4.0.1))
(org.apache.httpcomponents_httpclient_4.1.2_test,List(org.apache.httpcomponents_httpclient_4.0.1))
[info] Created C:\dev\community\.idea_modules/community.iml
[info] Created C:\dev\community\.idea_modules/community-build.iml

C:\dev\community>play compile
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dev\community\project
[info] Set current project to community (in build file:/C:/dev/community/)
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to C:\dev\community\target\scala-2.10\classes...
```

[image]

The `Unused import statement` is because no classes are being used in that package. This line can safely be removed by optimizing import: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>.

In this case I didn't add any scala libraries at all. I just compiled from the command line.

Comment: thank you for the detailed steps. cmd + alt + o removed all import statements because it assumes they were not used but actually they're in use. after that when i run the app, i get an error 'not found: type Controller'

Comment: @tylerdurden So if you create a new empty project following how I did would you still have the same error? You stated *Add scala compiler and library into external libraries.* in your question. What if you skip that part (though it shouldn't matter).

Comment: @tylerdurden Great! +1 for you! BTW it may be worth the upgrade to Ultimate edition since it has also full support for PHP, Python, Ruby and other good stuff (saw in your profile that you have answered som PHP questions). Those are plugins that have the same functionality as [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/).

Comment: yeap you're right as a polygot developer it would be nice to have all in one. let me try, if i like it then why not? otherwise vim still free :)